# How do I create/post a new managed object to server using Restkit 0.20.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, core-data, restkit

I'm having a very hard time finding documentation or examples of creating a new managed object, setting it's values, and saving to the server using Restkit.

I have a NSManagedObject Post:

```
@interface Post : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * postID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;

@end
```

This is my AppDelegate Setup:

```
// ---- BEGIN RestKit setup -----
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"My_App" ofType:@"momd"]];
// NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

// Enable Activity Indicator Spinner
[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

// Initialize the Core Data stack
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

// Set the default store shared instance
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

// Configure the object manager
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/v1"]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
NSString *auth_token = [[LUKeychainAccess standardKeychainAccess] stringForKey:@"auth_token"];  // Getting the Auth_Token from keychain
[objectManager.HTTPClient  setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:auth_token];

[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

// Setup Post entity mappping
RKEntityMapping *postMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[postMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"title":             @"title",
 @"text":       @"text",
 @"id":         @"postID"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *postResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:postMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"post" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:postResponseDescriptor];
```

Now, In my NewPostViewController when I click my "Save" button I have in my navbar, what do I need to do to save this post to my server?

Here's what I've tried, but it's not working correctly. I enter the success block and my server got the POST, but the fields are nil:

```
- (void)savePost {
    RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
    Post *post = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    [post setTitle:@"The Title"];
    [post setText:@"The Text"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:post path:@"posts" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success saving post");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure saving post: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you log the mapping result object?

Comment: My server responds back with the newly created Post, but nil for both title and text. Checking my rails output console it receives the POST request, but text and title is nil.

Comment: have you tried to access to them? CoreData may be loading it lazily.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The POSTed "post" sends nil for the title and text fields to the server, so there seems to be an issue with how I'm posting my new object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't added any RKRequestDescriptor's to your object manager. Without them, the poor object manager can't use key/value magic to serialize your object into an NSDictionary.

The thing that you HAVE added, the RKResponseDescriptor, describes how responses are managed. That's why you're seeing the success block called: RestKit has no idea what you're trying to send, but it recognizes the Post objects in the server response.

Try adding this below your responseDescriptor code:

```
RKRequestDescriptor * requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[postMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Post class] rootKeyPath:@"post"];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

(double check the keypath; I don't know what your API expects, so I went with what you had in the response descriptor)

Comment: Just what I was missing, thank you! I couldn't use `[postMapping inverseMapping]` though, because the id field was being set to 0, so I made a new requestDescriptor which left the id field out. The id is created on the server once the object is posted. Do I need to do any core data save as part of this? The return response is the newly created post, is that good enough? It matches the post responseDescriptor...

Comment: Its work...! But does reverse mapping required in get request?