# Restkit mapping issue - post newly created managed object to the server

Tags: core-data, http-post, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to post new managed object to the server by using rest kit, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting exception like the following:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '`RKRequestDescriptor` objects must be initialized with a mapping whose target class is `NSMutableDictionary`, got 'Users' (see `[RKObjectMapping requestMapping]`)'

I was looking for solution in stack overflow posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755266/how-do-i-create-post-a-new-managed-object-to-server-using-restkit-0-20-0)
This is my entity mapping method from MappingProvider class:

```
+(RKMapping *)usersMapping
{
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectStore:[[DateModel sharedDataModel]objectStore]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id": @"user_id",
                                              @"address1": @"address1",
                                              @"address2": @"address2",
                                              @"created_at":@"created_at",
                                              @"updated_at": @"updated_at",
                                              @"email": @"email",
                                              @"name":@"name",
                                              @"password_digest": @"password_digest",
                                              @"phone_no": @"phone_no",
                                              @"postcode":@"postcode",
                                              @"remember_token":@"remember_token",
                                              @"user_type": @"user_type",
                                              @"apns_token":@"apns_token"
                                              }
 ];

[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"admins" mapping:[MappingProvider adminsMapping]];
[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"carers" mapping:[MappingProvider carersMapping]];
[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"customers" mapping:[MappingProvider customersMapping]];
[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"userWearers" mapping:[MappingProvider customersMapping]];

return mapping;
```

This is the method called when user fill all the textfields and click the register button:

```
-(void)registerUser
{RKResponseDescriptor *userResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider usersMapping] method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
//here Xcode return exception
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider usersMapping] objectClass:[Users class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[[DateModel sharedDataModel]addResponseDescriptor:userResponseDescriptor];
[[DateModel sharedDataModel]addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[DateModel sharedDataModel]objectStore];

Users *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
user.email = _email;
user.password_digest  =_password;
user.name = _name;
user.address1 = _address;
user.postcode = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[_postcode integerValue]];
user.phone_no = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[_mobileNumber integerValue]];



[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Success saving user");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure saving user: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

}

Date-model setup method:

```
- (void)setup {
self.objectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"Setting up store at %@", path);
[self.objectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path
                          fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                               withConfiguration:nil
                                         options:[self optionsForSqliteStore]
                                           error:nil];

[self.objectStore createManagedObjectContexts];


//Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects

 self.objectStore.managedObjectCache =[[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc]initWithManagedObjectContext:self.objectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

// Set the default store shared instance
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:self.objectStore];
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the request descriptor is to convert your custom object into an `NSMutableDictionary` so that it can be serialised and sent. The mapping you're currently using is for converting into a `Users` object, so you need to use a different mapping.

RestKit has a convenience method that you can use:

```
... requestDescriptorWithMapping:[[MappingProvider usersMapping] inverseMapping] ...
```